# Dynamically change stddev of tf.truncated_normal in tensorflow

Tags: python, random, tensorflow

I am building a graph where I want the initial weight to have changeable standard deviation.
I tried to use the following command but it yielded an error:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
stddev = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1,50])
weight1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[50, 30],stddev=stddev))
result = tf.reduce_sum(tf.matmul(a, weight1))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(result , {a: np.random.randn(1, 50), stddev: 0.01}))
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?
I know that I can set `stddev` when define it, but the task that I am facing is to use a variant `stddev` during the process of training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`tf.placeholder_with_default`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder_with_default) like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

stddev = tf.placeholder_with_default(0.1, shape=(), name='stddev')
weight1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[50, 30], stddev=stddev))

a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1,50])
result = tf.reduce_sum(tf.matmul(a, weight1))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(sess.run(result , feed_dict={a: np.random.randn(1, 50), stddev: 0.01}))
```